# MacBook shows it is charging when MagSafe is green

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, magsafe

My MacBook currently shows this [image] even though the MagSafe charger has a green light.

Does anyone know why this is?

If it helps I am on a MacBook Air late 2010 with 819 cycle counts, 4,995mAh (currently), max capacity is 4,995mAh and the original capacity is 6,700mAh. I am also running `make` in terminal which has set my fans on and is making my computer lag a bit since it has a lot to install.

Could the issue be the process it using a lot of power?

**Edit**

Just clicked on my battery in the toolbar while pressing alt and found out it says `service battery` could this be a reason as well? (the message keeps appearing and disappearing)

Answer (score -3):

reset SMC
 look up how to reset SMC on macbook's without removable battery

Comment: Could it also be because there is a warning sating `service battery?`